# last 'x' not changing in list - python guess game

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
import random

listx = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
list0 = [random.randint(1, 9) for rm in range(9)]

while True:
  if('x' in listx):
    usr = int(input("Enter num:   "))
    for r in list0:
      if(r == usr):
        listx[list0.index(r)] = usr
        print(listx)
  else:
    print("End!")
    break
```

I want to hide random numbers behind 'x'
and let user guess them
but in the end program is not changing last 'x' to number

What should i do?

Comment: Hint: your `list0` isn't unique.

Comment: what do you want to do with duplicate values ? The user needs to request for the value once again? or it reveals every duplicate in a single guess?

Comment: @Clément once again

Comment: You can check if the corresponding index in `listx` doesn't contain an `"x"`, and if it doesn't, then continue searching

Comment: There's no need use parentheses for the __if__ statements, e.g. `if('x' in listx):` can be written as `if 'x' in listx:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import random

listx = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
list0 = [random.randint(1, 9) for rm in range(9)]

while True:
    if('x' in listx):
        usr = int(input("Enter num:   "))
        s = 0
        for r in list0:
            if(r == usr):
                listx[s] = usr
            s += 1
        print(listx)
    else:
        print("End!")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `list0` might have two elements with the same value. In that case, `list0.index(r)` always refers to the first element with that value, and, as a consequence, following values will not be guessed correctly.

Example:

```
list0 = [0, 1, 0]
listx = ['x', 'x', 'x']
```

- Let's say you guess 0. So `listx == [0, 'x', 'x']`
- Now you guess 1. So `listx == [0, 1, 'x']`
- And then you guess 0. But `listx == [0, 1, 'x']` (because you are referring to the first item, not the third one)

Answer (score 0):

`list0.index(r)` returns the lowest index where the element appears.

This will reveal every duplicate in a single guess.
Add `for idx in [i for i,d in enumerate(list0) if d==r]:` for getting multiple indices of matched value.

```
import random

listx = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
list0 = [random.randint(1, 9) for rm in range(9)]

while True:
  if('x' in listx):
    usr = int(input("Enter num:   "))
    for r in list0:
      if(r == usr):
        for idx in [i for i,d in enumerate(list0) if d==r]: # <--- Add this
            listx[idx] = usr
  else:
    print("End!")
    break
```

**Edit:**

Use the below code. If you remove `break` part then it will reveal all the duplicates value in a single guess, if not then it will reveal one character at a time.

```
import random

listx = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
list0 = [random.randint(1, 9) for rm in range(9)]

while True:
  if 'x' in listx:
    usr = int(input("Enter num:   "))
    for index_x, r in enumerate(list0):
      if((r == usr) & (listx[index_x]=='x')):
        listx[index_x] = usr
        break
    print(listx)

  else:
    print("End!")
    break
```

Comment: it worked thanks but when i put print(listx) under listx[idx] = usr it prints many same lists

Comment: print just below the `for idx` loop

Answer (score 0):

Given your wanted behavior ("guess again for duplicate value") you can use this trick :

```py
import random

listx = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
list0 = [random.randint(1, 9) for rm in range(9)]

print(list0)

while True:
    if('x' in listx):
        usr = int(input("Enter num:   "))
        for r in list0:
            if(r == usr):
                listx[list0.index(r)] = usr
                list0[list0.index(r)]=10 #dummy value
                print(listx)
                break
    else:
        print("End!")
        break
```

You just replace the first occurence by a dummy value and exit the for loop.